# Multiple remote login from same account causes all access tokens to refresh spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am comparatively new to Spring Boot and having a bit of difficulty to understand the entire structure of Spring Security. I am creating the tokens on request through oauth2 login endpoint and storing them inmemory. However, if multiple people login with the same account in separate devices, all the tokens are destroyed and recreated suddenly. This causes all my logged in users to get a forced session timeout.

I have searched the internet quite for long. Just need a solution that is more or less explained as, like I said, I am facing a bit of difficulty understanding Spring Security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, using in memory tokens created this issue. Not sure what is the reason behind that. Configured the Custom Token Store to use JDBC tokens. Using JDBC tokens creates two separate tables to protect the access and refresh tokens. Hence, even if multiple users are logged in simultaneously, the session is protect no matter what.

Check the following link for details (implementation): https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-oauth2-jdbc-token-store-example/